# java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

After creating an app in React-Native, I imported a third party component into Android. After the integration of this component, which worked on an Android app, on the app in React-Native it gives me this error:

```
2020-03-30 10:07:49.005 13979-13979/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartsign, PID: 13979
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartsign/com.smartsign.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
        ...
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.smartsign-LPgTscLKBMEXk1VohB6_Lw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.smartsign-LPgTscLKBMEXk1VohB6_Lw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.smartsign-LPgTscLKBMEXk1VohB6_Lw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerFactory.create(DevSupportManagerFactory.java:67) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.<init>(ReactInstanceManager.java:231) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:275) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:86) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:38) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp(ReactDelegate.java:103) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:88) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:83) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:44) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

How can I solve it to start the app that crashes right now when it opens?

Comment: Try cleaning project and rerun application. if this doesn't works please add the changes you made to adding that new library component.

Comment: @Parthshrivastav i have make new answare under this comment with the code i changed

Answer (score 24):

Do this it will solve the issue in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Could be a accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Add this in your app's *build.gradle*:

```
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}
```

Comment: I've already had this and it's still crashing for me. I upgraded min and target sdk versions and it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

With cleaning and re run this doesn't works.
This is the code i changed for adding the component.
***Top-level build.gradle*** under ***repositories***

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://haibison.bitbucket.io/maven-repos' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/pkix' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.onepf/openiab' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.drewnoakes/metadata-extractor' }
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3' }
maven { url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases' }
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //Gradle 3.x tools need to be retrieved from here as well
flatDir {
        dirs '../aar'
}
```

***App-level build.gradle*** under the ***defaultConfig*** block

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

***App-level build.gradle*** under the ***debug*** block in ***buildTypes*** block

```
debuggable true
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
```

***App-level build.gradle*** under the ***release*** block in ***buildTypes*** block

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
```

***App-level build.gradle*** under the ***dependencies*** block

```
ext.androidx_annotation = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_appcompat = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_cardview = '1.0.0'
ext.androidx_core = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_fragment = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_gridlayout = '1.0.0'
ext.androidx_legacy = '1.0.0'
ext.androidx_media = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_preference = '1.1.0'
ext.androidx_recyclerview = '1.0.0'

ext.qr_libs_version = "3.3.0" 
ext.lockpattern_version = "10.0.0" 
ext.jdom_version = "2.0.6" 
ext.jaxen_version = "1.1.6" 
ext.spongy_version = "1.54.0.0" 
ext.openiab_version = "0.9.8.7" 
ext.metadataextractor_version = "2.9.1" 
ext.jcifs_version = "1.3.18-kohsuke-1" 
ext.commonslang_version = "3.5" 
ext.aboutlibraries_libs_version = "6.2.3" 

dependencies {
    api 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    api 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK', ext:'aar')
    api "haibison.android:lockpattern:$lockpattern_version" 
    api "androidx.annotation:annotation:$androidx_annotation" 
    api "androidx.core:core:$androidx_core" 
    api "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:$androidx_legacy" 
    api "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:$androidx_legacy" 
    api "androidx.media:media:$androidx_media" 
    api "androidx.fragment:fragment:$androidx_fragment" 
    api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidx_appcompat" 
    api "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$androidx_gridlayout" 
    api "androidx.preference:preference:$androidx_preference" 
    api "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidx_recyclerview" 
    api "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidx_cardview" 
    api (name:'Sources_Custom_Support_Library_v4', ext:'aar')
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK_JniBitmapOperationsLibrary', ext:'aar')
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK_QRCodeScanner', ext:'aar')
    api ("com.google.zxing:core:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("com.google.zxing:android-core:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("com.google.zxing:android-integration:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("org.jdom:jdom2:$jdom_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("jaxen:jaxen:$jaxen_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:$spongy_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("org.onepf:openiab:$openiab_version")
    api ("com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:$metadataextractor_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:$jcifs_version") {transitive = true;}
    api("com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:$aboutlibraries_libs_version") { transitive = true; }
    api ("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonslang_version")
}
```

and in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** into the  tag

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.DocumentImage" 
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
            android:label="@string/significant_app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.CaptureSignature" 
            android:label="@string/significant_app_name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.AndroidExplorer" 
            android:label="@string/explorer" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.MainSettingsActivity" 
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_settings" 
            android:logo="@mipmap/icon">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
                android:value="com.xyzmo.ui.DocumentImage" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.SIGNificantLockpatternActivity" 
            android:theme="@style/Significant.Lockpattern.Theme" 
            tools:replace="android:theme" 
            android:label="@string/xyzmo_lockpattern_titlebar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
                android:value="com.xyzmo.ui.DocumentImage" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xyzmo.kiosk.ui.AdvertisementActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"></activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.xyzmo.ui.AboutActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/SIGNificant_AboutTheme"></activity>
```

Comment: damn, that much dependencies :O

Answer (score -1):

My case was I was using an android emulator that build on SDK API 16. Creating new emulator upper than SDK 16 is work like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

and **remove it** from `/app/build.gradle`

in my case that was causing the crash.