# Porting react native project from ios to android

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

Hey guys I have been working on a react native ios project for ~5 months and i need to port it over to android. The problem is when i get it on the android emulator every time i open it it just crashes and I have no idea why I've scoured the internet but nobody else seems to be having this problem.

Below i've attached a screenshot of the fatal error that causes the crash on logcat as well as a screenshot of my dependencies in app/build.gradle. Any ideas?

[Fatal error on logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8qq1.png)

[app/build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZcM9.png)

Some people said changing the app/build.gradle file in multiple places would fix the issue but it didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926425/java-lang-runtimeexception-requested-enabled-devsupportmanager-but-devsupportm)

Comment: My issue is BridgeDevSupportManager, not DevSupportManagerImpl. I saw that post already it didnt help unfortunately.